# Where can I find the Spring Documentation for Gradle Application Properties Configuration?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Where can I find the Spring Documentation for Gradle Application Properties Configuration? Image below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUQAt.png)

Answer (score 1):

The Spring properties documentation is scattered across several places, and it depends on which Spring components you're using.

It would be best to open your project with an IDE such as IntelliJ, which will help showing you the properties javadoc directly from your `application.properties` file.

For the common properties, see this link:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html

Comment: Thank you very much! I am currently using Spring Data JPA for my application properties right now, thanks again!

Comment: Section 5 in the link above

Answer (score 0):

[Spring Gradle Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/)

You can get started with this.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am currently using Spring Data JPA for my application properties right now, thanks again!